# How to export particular columns in CSV format?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have data.csv file:

```
Q,W,E,R,T,Y
A,S,D,F,G,H
```

To load this file I am using this code:

```
d3.text("data.csv", function(data) {
    parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);
    // Some data manipulations...
    // How to export 2nd & 4th column in CSV format?
}
```

How to export 2nd and 4th column from **parsedCSV** object in CSV fromat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
d3.text("data.csv", function(data) {
    var header = data.split('\n')[0].split(',').map(function(name) {
        return name.trim();
    });
    var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);
    var columns = parsedCSV.map(function(row) {
        return [row[header[1]], row[header[3]]];
    });
});
```

Comment: It works and without header by changing return line to: return [row[1], row[3]];

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way will be to provide an accessor function as the second argument to `d3.csv.parseRows()`:

```
var columns;

d3.text("data.csv", function(data) {
  columns = d3.csv.parseRows(csv, function(row) {
    return [row[1], row[3]];
  });
};
```

From the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/CSV#parseRows):

> This function is invoked for each row in the CSV file, being passed the current row and index as two arguments. The return value of the function replaces the element in the returned array of rows;